# Action Button does not work (SceneBuilder JavaFX)

Tags: java, button, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to switch a scene using a button which created by Scene Builder.

That is my Controller class

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML Button LoginButton;

       @FXML private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

            Parent tableViewParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../FXML/MainMenu.fxml"));
            Scene tableViewScene = new Scene(tableViewParent);

            Stage window = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            window.setScene(tableViewScene);
            window.show();
        }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


    }
```

And there is FXML

```
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.4" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.Controller">

    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
    <AnchorPane id="login" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ccf2ff #ccf2ff;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane id="login2" layoutX="320.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="316.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="95.0" promptText="Login">
                     <effect>
                        <InnerShadow />
                     </effect></TextField>
                  <PasswordField alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="159.0" promptText="Password">
                     <effect>
                        <InnerShadow blurType="TWO_PASS_BOX" />
                     </effect></PasswordField>
                  <Button layoutX="129.0" layoutY="220.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Button" />

               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
    </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

For some reason IntelliJ shows error Cannot resolve 'handleButtonAction'

> `onAction="#handleButtonAction"`

Comment: There are more issues with ther fxml: The `</children>` tag in the penultimate line is never opened which means this is not a valid xml file...

Comment: ActionEvent event is not necessary try private void handleButtonAction(){//code}

Comment: @CarlosLópez Then, how the code suppose to look like in order to change the scene?

Comment: can you post the error code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the Scene (and the Stage) with any FXML element belonging to it. You only have to do `anyElement.getScene().getWindow()`

```
public class Controller {

   @FXML 
   Button loginButton;

   @FXML 
   private void handleButtonAction() {

      Parent tableViewParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../FXML/MainMenu.fxml"));
      Scene tableViewScene = new Scene(tableViewParent);

      // Instead of retrieving the stage by the event's source, you can do it by one of your FXML component.
      Stage window = (Stage) loginButton.getScene().getWindow();
      window.setScene(tableViewScene);
      window.show();
   }


   @FXML
   public void initialize() {
      //initialize the field you want here.
   }
}
```

And the FXML :

```
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.4" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.Controller">
   <!-- Fabian was right, you forgot this children. -->
   <children>
      <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
         <AnchorPane id="login" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ccf2ff #ccf2ff;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <children>
               <AnchorPane id="login2" layoutX="320.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="316.0">
                  <children>
                     <TextField alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="95.0" promptText="Login">
                        <effect>
                           <InnerShadow />
                        </effect>
                     </TextField>
                     <PasswordField alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="159.0" promptText="Password">
                        <effect>
                           <InnerShadow blurType="TWO_PASS_BOX" />
                        </effect>
                     </PasswordField>
                  <Button fx:id="loginButton" layoutX="129.0" layoutY="220.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Button" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Some explanation/remarks on your code.

Useless to implements Initializable since JavaFX 8. `initialize` method with FXML annotation is now sufficient (look at the [note in interface definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html)).

Change the loginButton with a lowercase for the first letter ([Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))

Fabian is right in his comment, you forgot the children starting element for VBox node in your FXML.

I did not found the loginButton `fx:id` in your FXML. Did you forget it ? I added it in `Button` element in the FXML. (I do not know if it was effectively the loginButton...)

Comment: I've made necessary changes but it seems like there is still some errors. In the Controller shows: "Cannot resolve method 'getScene()'.  Moreover, in the FXML where I added "fx:id="loginButton"", it shows "Cannot set javafx,scene.control.Button to field 'loginButton"

Comment: Forst the first error : are you sure you import `javafx.scene.control.Button` in your Controller ?
For the FXML, "fx:id="loginButton" you copy in comment, I suspect there is a supplementary quotemark or apostrophe according to the message you copy. It is `<Button fx:id="loginButton" text="Button" [...] />`.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in your controller

```
@FXML
protected void handleButtonAction() {
    System.out.println("In handleButtonAction");
// your logic 
}
```

and  **FXML file**

```
<Button layoutX="129.0" layoutY="220.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Button" />
```

I hope it will work... I used scenebuilder for **FXML**, if not works send me error screenshot